# On RestController requestBody is getting changed

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, junit5

**Test Case**

I am writing integration test using Junit5 and RestTemplate.
I captured screen shots while debugging when the call leaves from Test case to calling endpoint, here is the snapshot1, in snapshot1, take a look at tasks (key) the value is ArrayList of size 2

[image]
**text on screenshot is --> only one or last elelment in tasks list reached target endpoint**

here is the code snippet which calls the target endpoint from test case

```
ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(serverUrl + endpoint, HttpMethod.valueOf(httpMethod), input, String.class, params);
```

**Target Endpoint**

Once the request reaches target endpoint, here is snapshot2, in snapshot2, take a look at tasks (key) the value is LinkedHashMap,
**not sure how come the data structure changed from Arraylist to LinkedHashmap?
Is Springframework doing this translation? Have no clue**

**one more observation to add is only the last element of tasks list from test case is sent to target endpoint**

[image]

target endpoint is developed using springboot (dependencies included are spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter, jackson-dataformat-xml...etc, all are routine/common dependencies)
spring.boot.version = 2.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: Could you maybe post the test case and the code under test?

Comment: I fixed it, in my test I need to add Content-Type : "application/json" in headers
else you would end up seeing this weird behavior